# Formally proving a multi-variable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

So I'm having trouble writing a formal (and complete) proof in Multi-variable calculus. For example, there is the following question:

Show that $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (1, 1)} (x+y) = 2.$$

I know that we will proceed, like we did in one-variable calculus, by finding an appropriate value for $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$ by doing some scratch work and then plugging it in in order to end up with the $\mid f(x)-L\mid < \epsilon$. Thereby ending the proof.

Can someone please construct a formal and complete proof as to how this will be tackled step-by-step so that I may be able to learn proving in multi-variable calculus? It will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|(x+y)-2|=|x-1+y-1| \le |x-1|+|y-1|$

Your turn !

Comment: I don't think you understood my query. I see the mathematics: $\left | x-1 \right | +\left | y-1 \right |\leqslant 2\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1^2)}
=2\left \| (x, y) - (1, 1)\right \| < \epsilon$. And so we will take $\delta=\epsilon/2$. Then what? I am asking for a complete formal proof so that I may learn how to formally prove other cases.

Comment: What is your problem ? Given $\epsilon >0$ take $ \delta=\epsilon /2$. If $||(x,y)-(1,1)||< \delta$ then $|x+y-2| < \epsilon$

Comment: I just need someone to show me how it is formally done. That is all. I just need the whole thing written somewhere once.